# Writing to one file from different methods in R

Tags: r, csv, xlsx

In general, I'm trying to create R code that reads questions from different txt files (test1.txt, test2.txt,...) and creates one file (exam.txt). In other words, I have different questions pool files and I'd like to create one exam file out of them. Type of questions (true/false, Multiple-choices, short-answer question, fill in he spaces, table matching ).  The reason I chose to go with txt file because MS docx files are not supported by R ( unless I go through long process  [as pointed in this blog](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/write-ms-word-document-using-r-with-as-little-overhead-as-possible/)  )

I found [exams package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exams/index.html) to create exams, which is not exactly what I want.

A simple approach would be reading files one by one and dump the questions in a single file(exam.txt). I'm facing two problems:

1-How to write the already read contents to a file (exam.txt -Note: txt or csv or xlsx is fine, however, I prefer txt for simplicity) and keep it open for the next file contents.

2- How to choose how many questions to read from each file.

I have tried the following:

```
ReadTxt<-function(){
fileName="test1.txt"
conn=file(fileName,open="r",encoding = 'UTF-8')
linn=readLines(conn)
for (i in 1:length(linn)){
   if (!(grepl("#",linn[i])) )
   cat(linn[i],"\n")
}
close(conn)
}
```

I have used `#` as a separator between question in each txt file. That's why I'm using grepl command.

sample of `test1.txt:`

```
First question goes here
#
Second question
#
Third question 
#
```

Full R code would be something like this:

```
createExam<-function(){ 
ReadTxt("test1.txt")
#ReadTxt("test2.txt")
#ReadTxt("test3.txt")
 }

ReadTxt<-function(fname){
fileName=fname
conn=file(fileName,open="r",encoding = 'UTF-8')
linn=readLines(conn)
for (i in 1:length(linn)){
  if (!(grepl("#",linn[i])) )
  cat(linn[i],"\n")
 }
 close(conn)


 }
```

Comment: I think I did, the first part of my question to show the effort I did and existing alternatives. Also, this is a reproducible example.. You can run the code!

Comment: Sorry, too much "overhead", didn't see it. ;-) So the task is to a.) read files of the form testNUMS.txt in one folder, b.) cut out # lines in those files and c.) write the results to an output file?

Comment: I'm not understanding the difficulty. There is an `append` argument to the `write` and `cat` functions.

Comment: @ lukeA. Yes, good summary

Answer (score 1):

You can first read all questions in memory and then write them to disk

Considering your test files:

```
$ cat test1.txt 
1 First question goes here
#
1 Second question
#
1 Third question 
#
$ cat test2.txt 
2 First question goes here
#
2 Second question
#
2 Third question 
#
$ cat test3.txt 
3 First question goes here
#
3 Second question
#
3 Third question 
#
```

this R syntax reads all files in memory, then prints a subset of the questions to a file

```
createExam<-function(){
  res <- list()
  res <- ReadTxt("test1.txt", res)
  res <- ReadTxt("test2.txt", res)
  res <- ReadTxt("test3.txt", res)
  return(res)
}

ReadTxt<-function(fname, res){
  fileName=fname
  conn=file(fileName,open="r",encoding = 'UTF-8')
  linn=readLines(conn)
  for (i in 1:length(linn)){
      if (!(grepl("#",linn[i])) )
      res[[length(res)+1]]<-linn[i]
    }
    close(conn)
    return(res)
}

questions <- createExam()
subset <- questions[c(1,2,4,5,7,8)]
conn=file("exam.txt",open="w",encoding = 'UTF-8')
for (i in 1:length(subset)){
  writeLines(subset[[i]], conn)
}
close(conn)
```

The above gives the result

```
$ Rscript t.R 
$ cat exam.txt 
1 First question goes here
1 Second question
2 First question goes here
2 Second question
3 First question goes here
3 Second question
```

Comment: Thank you. It's close to what I want. However, how do I automate the  process of choosing questions from each file. Like 2 questions from test1.txt and 1 question from test2.txt. or like random between (x, y), where s=1 and y= max number of questions in a file.

Comment: in your code you explicitly provide line's number. "subset <- questions[c(1,2,4,5,7,8)]"